# combining cloudbees ec2 docker image with docker in docker

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

Am trying to combine docker in docker feature with in [cloudbees ecs](https://github.com/cloudbees/jnlp-slave-with-java-build-tools-dockerfile/blob/master/Dockerfile) image.
Both the images are build using different linux based distribution.
Cloudbees ECS slave image is build use base ubuntu 14.04 and [docker:1.8-dind](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/866c3fbd87e8eeed524fdf19ba2d63288ad49cd2/1.11/dind/Dockerfile) is build from base debian:jessie. What is the best way to combine both into one docker image with both features using debian:jessie as the base.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar in the past and it usually comes down to walking the Dockerfile dependency chain and building up the image that way. In your instance, you'd probably want to start at https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudbees/java-build-tools/~/dockerfile/ and swap out

```
FROM ubuntu:15.04
```

with

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

And build it to see what works and what doesn't work. Typically it's a package manager or something that needs to be updated/replaced.

The downside of this approach is that it can be a lot of trial and error and you end up with giant Dockerfiles, but the upside is that you can usually streamline your image to do exactly what you want without a lot of the Ubuntu extras.

Comment: Thanks @mchesier i have done the same... Some package & their dependency is different troubleshooting same. one example jdk 8 not avail in jessie.. supports only jdk7... i need to figure this out why.....

Comment: I hate to say it, but you're probably going to have to move one or the other. Probably start with:

    FROM java:7-jre and build from there.